# memorystream contains bad xml markup when read

Tags: c#, xml, stream, httpwebresponse

What is my issue here?  When I write the stream back out to web, open the file it contains some of the content but all malformed and some missing.

Am I experiencing loss of data due to a logic error?

**Note:** the readstream and writestream below mocks up what a service will be filling in.  I will be receiving a stream to read from the service.  I'll need to write that stream back out.

```
        MemoryStream writeStream = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        OrderDocument doc = new OrderDocument();
        doc.Format = "xml";
        doc.DocumentId = "5555555";
        doc.Aid = "ZZ";
        doc.PrimaryServerPort = "PORT";
        MemoryStream readStream = new MemoryStream(doc.GetDocument());
        while (readStream != null && readStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
        {
            writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        writeStream.Flush();
        writeStream.Position = 0;
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();

        Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}.xml", doc.DocumentId));
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", writeStream.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(writeStream.ToArray());
        Response.End();
```

Comment: What is `OrderDocument`? What does `doc.GetDocument()` do? What data do these contain?
Also, this could be a problem of encoding. What you describe sounds like what happens when a text reader confuses between UTF-8 and ASCII. Play around with the encoding of the output.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I experiencing loss of data due to a logic error?

Yes probably, you may try simplifying your code a little bit. I don't really see the need of multiple memory streams here:

```
OrderDocument doc = new OrderDocument();
doc.Format = "xml";
doc.DocumentId = "5555555";
doc.Aid = "ZZ";
doc.PrimaryServerPort = "PORT";
byte[] buffer = doc.GetDocument();

Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}.xml", doc.DocumentId));
Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Comment: This is a test page I created that is mocking up what a service call will provide me.  I will be receiving a stream response from service and will need to write that back out.